# one Javascript function for mutiple div ids

Tags: javascript, html, function

i have 3 Div ids as  "shirts", "hoodies", "other" 
then i have a JavaScript function. How would i be able to use the same Js function for all 3 of these ids?

```
function myAccFunc() {
  var x = document.getElementById("divID");
  if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
    x.className += " w3-show";
  } else {
    x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
  }
}
```

Comment: Put all the ids in an array and loop them, pass the id as your function param and use it.

Comment: you can give all divs a common class and change the reference in your function from id to class

Comment: @LelioFaieta Keyboard drop

Comment: @axelduch thanks for noticing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling the function this:

```
myAccFunc("shirts");
myAccFunc("hoodies");
myAccFunc("other");
```

and the function of this way:

```
function myAccFunc(div){
    var x = document.getElementById(div);
    if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1){
        x.className += " w3-show";
    }else{
        x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
    }
}
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
function myAccFunc(id){
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  if( !x ) return;

  if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1)
    x.className += " w3-show";
  else
    x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
}  


['id1', 'id2', 'id3'].forEach(myAccFunc);
```

You might be interested in using [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) (ES2015). it's quite nicely supported except old IE.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another class to the divs you want to edit and call for that instead.  Also, why use `indexOf` for checking existence when you can use `includes`

```
var x = document.getElementsByClass('checkClass');
for (i=0;i<x.length - 1;i++){
   if (!x[i].className.includes("w3-show")){
      x[i]className += " w3-show";
   } else {
     x[i].className = x.className.replace(" w3-    show", "");
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**I'm assuming you don't want to show all of them by default**

You could pass the div_id as a param and then use event listeners to call functions for each div.

```
func myAccFunc(div_id){
   var x = document.getElementById(div_id);
   // rest of your code here
}

// event listeners
document.getElementById("show_shirts_btn").addEventListener("click", function(){ 
         myAccFunc(shirts) 
    });

document.getElementById("show_hoodies_btn").addEventListener("click", function(){ 
         myAccFunc(hoodies) 
    });


document.getElementById("show_other_btn").addEventListener("click", function(){ 
         myAccFunc(other) 
    });
```